# Plotting amplitude spectrum of audio signal

Tags: matlab, audio, fft, octave, spectrum

I am doing a short-time fourier transformation on my WAV-File. Basically what i am doing is a real-time spectral analysis. To understand, what i mean, I advise you to try my code. Just take any WAV-File and put it in your matlab/octave directory. Anyway, the question is how do i get the amplitude spectrum from my audio signal? Btw, my one-sided spectrum signal is contained in the variable "Yres".

```
%% OCTAVE-Program

[y,fs]=wavread('UnchainMyHeart.wav');
%Reading wav-file

t=linspace(0,length(y)/fs,length(y));
%Creating time vector

plot(t,y) %Drawing signal in the time domain
fftlen = 4096; 
segl =floor(0.05*fs); %Length of Segment 

windowshift=segl/2; 
window=hann(segl); %Optimizing hanning-function in a variable
window=window.';

si=1; %Start Index
ei=segl; %End Index

AOS= length(y)/windowshift - 1;
f1=figure;


f=0:1:fftlen-1;
f=f/(fftlen-1)*fs;

Ya=zeros(1,fftlen);
plot(f,Ya),axis([0 fs -90 20])

grid on 


n=0;

for m= 1:1:AOS

y_a = y(si:ei);
y_a= y_a.*window;
Ya=fft(y_a, fftlen);

n=n+1;
if n==1
  Yres=abs(Ya);
  else
  Yres=Yres+abs(Ya);
end

if n=10
  Yres=Yres/10;
  n=0;

  drawnow; %Updating the frames


figure(f1);
plot(f(1:end/2), 20*log10(abs(Yres(1:end/2))));

ylim([-90 20]);

title("One-sided Spectrum of audio signal");    
xlabel("f(Hz)"); 
ylabel("dB");

grid on;

end

si=si+windowshift; %Update Start Index  
ei=ei+windowshift; %Update End Index

end
```

Comment: What is the "amplitude" spectrum? There is magnitude and phase. You are already plotting the one-sided magnitude.

Comment: Don't know how to explain, english is not my mother language. https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html    If you click on the link and scroll down to the picture (single sided....S(t)). Is something like that possible with my audio signal? Maybe i also lack the knowledge of how the fft works in general. Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, your code already does it.

Comment: That kind of plot is more normally called a [Spectral Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) plot.

Comment: it's implemented in the Octave signal package and called `specgram` UTSL!